# Filter item iteration in dataframe (with FOR or any other)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, iteration

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1989, 100],
                  ['A', 1990, 200],
                  ['A', 2017, 100],
                  ['B', 1989, 500],
                  ['B', 1990, 200],
                  ['C', 1990, 200],
                  ['C', 19870, 400]],
                 columns=['Univers', 'year', 'amount'])
```

```
    Univer  year   amount
0       A   1989     100
1       A   1990     200
2       A   2017     100
3       B   1989     500
4       B   1990     200
5       C   1990     200
6       C  19870     400
.
.
.
```

I would like to perform a filter by `Univer`. I applied only for A `d2 = d[d['Univers']=='A']`:

```
 Univers  year  amount
0       A  1989     100
1       A  1990     200
2       A  2017     100
```

Now, imagine I have a thousand of items in **`Univers`** column (and their corresponding ítems in the dataframe), how can I do this for the remaining items in **`Univers`** using a `FOR` (or any other)?

Comment: Sorry, what is your expected result? You want to get slices of each unique university?

Comment: @coolspeed Yes, slices or even export the result in a csv file. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
Perform a `groupby` on `Univers`, since you need to save each group.

```
for i, g in df.groupby('Univers'):
    g.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(i))
```

This generates 3 files -

`A.csv`

```
  Univers  year  amount
0       A  1989     100
1       A  1990     200
2       A  2017     100
```

`B.csv`

```
  Univers  year  amount
3       B  1989     500
4       B  1990     200
```

`C.csv`

```
  Univers   year  amount
5       C   1990     200
6       C  19870     400
```

---

**Option 2**
Another alternative would be to call `pd.Series.unique` and then filter on this condition -

```
for v in df.Univers.unique():
    df[df.Univers == v].to_csv('{}.csv'.format(i))
```

Which does the same thing. You can also use `query`/`eval` to perform filtering.

Comment: Option_1 performs amazing! Just one last question: how do I apply a simple sort (by year) before upload them as a csv file? (for example in C.csv).  I am trying to apply some `.sort_values(by=[year], ascending=[True])` but I don't know how to extend it in the iteration. thanks in advanced.

Comment: @newbie You should use: for i, g in df.sort_values("year").groupby("Univers", sort=False): ... and I think it should do the trick. Make sure "year" is a column of integers.

Comment: @coldspeed may I ask what would be your approach if you want to replace last cell of `year` column  in all csv file generated before? I tried `for i, g in df.sort_values("year").groupby("univers", sort=False):
    for y in g.iloc[-1, g.columns.get_loc('year')]:
        y = end
    g.to_csv('{}.xls'.format(i))` but it didn´t work (I got the same result as before). thanks!

Comment: @newbie What do you want to replace it with? You seem to be on the right track, but it's hard to visualise without seeing any input or expected output. Can you open a question?

Comment: @coldspeed I will open a new question.

Comment: I doubt things like this can ever be done without for loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple (and probably not optimized) way:

```
key_name = 'Univers'
univers = set(d[key_name])
for uni in univers:
    print d[d[key_name] == uni]
```

Output:

```
Univers  year  amount
0       A  1989     100
1       A  1990     200
2       A  2017     100

Univers   year  amount
5       C   1990     200
6       C  19870     400

Univers  year  amount
3       B  1989     500
4       B  1990     200
```

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that you have  a list of acceptable values for "Univer" in another dataframe lets say x...

x
Univers  Col2

A        test1

B        test2

C        test3

You can join both the dataframes and filter out the rows which you need.
Approx syntax
result = pd.concat([d, x], on='Univers').. Is that what you wanted?