# Replacing cell of a dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, replace, filter

I was working on this question [filter iteration using FOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066677/filter-item-iteration-in-dataframe-with-for-or-any-other/48066870?noredirect=1#comment83143275_48066870). I wonder how to replace the last cell of `year` column in each csv file generated. Lets say I want to replace the last cell (of column `year`) of each cvs file by current year (2018). I did the following code:

```
for i, g in df.sort_values("year").groupby("Univers", sort=False):
    for y in g.iloc[-1, g.columns.get_loc('year')]:
        y = 2018
    g.to_csv('{}.xls'.format(i))
```

But I get the same column with any changes. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be of two fold: first find the index of the last row and then replace it at (last_row_idx, "year").

Try this

```
for i, g in df.sort_values("year").groupby("Univers", sort=False):
    last_row_idx = g.tail(1).index.item()  # first task: find index
    g.at[last_row_idx, "year"] = 2018      # replace
    g.to_csv('{}.xls'.format(i))
```

Alternatively, one can also use `g.set_value(last_row_idx, "year", 2018)` to set value at a particular cell.

#### Reference

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html

[Set value for particular cell in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe)

[Get index of a row of a pandas dataframe as an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217310/get-index-of-a-row-of-a-pandas-dataframe-as-an-integer)